# Dissolve numpy array into binary array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

which I want to convert/dissolve into

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

my current approach is to first use a while loop to split the array into just `1`s and then create an array based on `np.where(x>0)`. I however believe that this is not the most efficient and elegant numpy solution. any ideas on how to improve this?

```
source = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.,
                   2., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=np.int)

diss = None
while np.any(source):
    row = np.greater(source, 0).astype(np.int)
    if diss is None:
        diss = row
    else:
        diss = np.vstack([diss, row])
    source -= row

idx = np.where(diss > 0)
result = np.zeros((0,source.shape[0]), dtype=np.int)
for x, y in zip(*idx):
    row = np.zeros(source.shape, dtype=np.int)
    row[y] = 1
    result = np.vstack([result, row])
```

Comment: Is the order of the rows critical?

Comment: No, the order is not critical. The important thing is that any value >1 gets broken down into ones.

Comment: What is the typical value for `source.max()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
In [38]: x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,0,0])

In [39]: n = x.sum()

In [40]: rows = np.arange(n)

In [41]: positions = np.nonzero(x)[0]

In [42]: cols = np.repeat(positions, x[positions])

In [43]: result = np.zeros((n, len(x)), dtype=int)

In [44]: result[rows, cols] = 1

In [45]: result
Out[45]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I've timed both possible answers, and this one is faster: `10000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 µs per loop` vs `10000 loops, best of 3: 36.2 µs per loop`

Answer (score 2):

For your example, this is about 5 times faster, and it doesn't damage `source`.

```
source = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], int)
m, h, w = source.max(), source.sum(), len(source)
i = np.concatenate([np.nonzero(source>i)[0] for i in xrange(m)])
result = np.zeros((h,w), int)
result[range(h), i] = 1
```

There is still a loop of length `source.max()` so if that is large (for the example it's only two) perhaps something better can be done.

Comment: `source-i>0` seems like it'd be better written as `source>i`.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112, it started as `np.nonzero(source - i)` before I realized it was counting negative values.  That actually saves about 10% of the time :P